# changing component to function in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following reactJS component:

```
const Breadcrumbs = () => <Route path="*" render={props => {
    let parts = props.location.pathname.split("/").filter(part => part.indexOf('#') === -1);
    const place = parts[parts.length - 1];
    parts = parts.slice(1, parts.length - 1);
    return (<div>
        <ol className={`breadcrumb`}>
            {parts.map(crumb)}
            <li>{place}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>);
}}/>;
```

At the moment My Issue is that this component is called only once. And not on each page reload.

How can I change this Component to a function that I can use it in `componentDidMount()`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're actually already creating a functional component. Your code is assigning everything to the right of that initial `=` to the constant `Breadcrumbs`. To the right, you have an arrow functions.

To call your component, you can do `Breadcrumbs(props)`

Comment: When I do this `{() => Breadcrumbs(this.props)}` nothing is printed in view. When I do this `<Breadcrumbs/>`it is only printed when I refresh the browser

Comment: The first piece of JSX above is returning a function definition, I believe. The 2nd example is returning the Object that JSX expects. Take a look here for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.